# How to TDD with Internet-Dependency in Python?

Tags: python, unit-testing, tdd

I need to make sure that I have a **function** that can **download zip files** from a **list of links** and write the file into the "zip_files/" folder.

I am dependent on the outside webpage for the links and zip files!

```
Since you:
- shouldn't mock
- don't rely on outside dependencies
- want to have confidence your code works!
```

I feel I need a test to show me there is a working function to download a zip-file.

---

**WHY do I need the function?**
My python script shall return a JSON-file with two lists (years, grades).
The process to get the data is as follows:

1. Go to Webpage
2. Get list of all -tags with "class=zip_download"
3. Download every zip on that list
4. Unzip files and move Excel-files to "excel_files/" (Need to back excel-files up for later!)
5. Run calculations on every Excel to extract desired JSON

I am stuck writing tests for **the third (3.) step** and feel my thinking is too tightly coupled with the implementation.

---

```
    def test_after_download_have_more_zip_files_than_links_in_list(self):
        """
        GIVEN: I provide a list of links
        WHEN: Downloading is finished
        THEN: My folder has at least as many zip files as the list items
        """

        zip_download_folder = "zip_files"
        list_of_zip_links = load_json_data(zip_link_file)

        download_zip_links(list_of_zip_links, zip_download_folder)

        self.assertGreater(len(os.listdir(zip_download_folder)), list_of_zip_links)
        for file in os.listdir(zip_download_folder):
            self.assertEqual(file.endswith('.zip'))
```

**How do I write a useful test here?**

Comment: It depends on how deep you need your test to go. What's your `download_zip_links` implementation like?

Comment: Also, you can avoid writing the code in the first place, so you don't need to test it. If you use [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/), step 3 and first half of 4 just becomes: `file_objs = [open(url) for url in list_of_zip_links]`

Comment: The implementation doesn‘t exist yet. But I would for-loop through the links, make a get request and move the file to the zip folder

Comment: Smart-open might be a good way. But the Test should come before the implementation 

Answer (score 1):

> How do I write a useful test here?

If you were doing TDD, your test subject (download_zip_links ?) would probably be a *callable*, loosely coupled to dependencies that are inconvenient in a red-green-refactor loop.

That might mean that (for the tests that we are running every time we refactor) those dependencies are realized using dynamically generated mocks, or it might be that they are using null/inert substitutes.

For an action like "Download this link from the internet", there are a number of edge cases that we might want to handle in our logic (and therefore simulate in our tests that make sure that we get the logic right); these might include a successful HTTP response, an unsuccessful HTTP response, a network failure, a timeout....

Having the ability to simulate these conditions cost effectively makes proving your handling logic a lot easier.  You "just" couple your test subject to a simulator that pretends the third download failed, or whatever, and then measure to see that the right things happen (whatever that should be in your case).

It may be useful to review:

- http://docs.eventide-project.org/user-guide/useful-objects.html
- https://www.jamesshore.com/v2/projects/nullables/testing-without-mocks

Answer (score 0):

IMO your post demonstrates one drawback of TDD -- the prioritization on testing can mean a reduced consideration of the best abstractions to use around relevant implementation details.

For example, you've defined these two steps/abstractions:

> 3. Download every zip on that list
> 4. Unzip files and move Excel-files to "excel_files/"

But this particular implementation is somewhat arbitrary, and now you're worried about how to TDD implementation details with side effects like API calls and disk IO.

My suggestion is that these implementation details (probably) don't matter to you, so don't test for them. Here's a separate list of abstractions that I think you'll find easier to test that can also solve your use-case:

```py
def zipurls_at(target_url, css: "*")
    # your impl here
    return zipurls 

def parse_excel(excel_fobj):
    # your impl here
    return data

def compute_json(data):
    # your impl here
    return json_data
```

For example:

```py
from smart_open import open

def script_core(webpage_url):
    excel_zip_urls = zipurls_at(webpage_url, css: ".zip_download")

    def output_json(excel_fobj):
       return compute_json(parse_excel(excel_fobj))

    return [output_json(open(s3_uri)) for uri in excel_zip_urls]
```

Nothing above cares about whether it's stored to disk. It could even be implemented to be 100% in-memory without changing tests. However, if you really want to store to disk, you could do that easily with a function that takes a file object, saves it to some location, returning the path where it's saved.

Comment: I don‘t see this as a limit of TDD. More of my way of thinking not yet being compatible. All I know how to use is a hammer. Every problem looks like a nail to me 

Comment: But this rethinking of abstraction is what I‘ve been looking for!! Will try it out